# mysql selecting columns passed on another column from another table

Tags: mysql, select

Hello everyone I have 2 tables (table1,table2):

```
Table1: column1, column2
Table2: column3, column4
```

Where column1 = column3 (different names).

I would like to select column1 , column2 only if column4 not like '%x%';

How can i do that and whats the statement for it?

I tried looking for answers but couldnt quite get it!?

Comment: So you want to join two tables based on column 1 and column 3

Comment: **SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column3 WHERE t2.column4 not like '%x%';**

Comment: what's t1 and table1 ? are they the same ?

Comment: @ankitbug94 i dont know what you mean but maybe ? the other guys answer didnt help.